# Insert into two rows, get AI key of first row and apply to the second insert.

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm making a forum system from scratch and I've run into a small snag in the code. The code looks like this:

```
    function post($title, $body, $uid, $visible)
{
    if(strlen($title) <= 0 || strlen($body) <= 0)
    {
        return false;   
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user_threads(title,uid,postDate) VALUES(:title, :uid, NOW()); SELECT threadID FROM user_threads WHERE title = :title2 AND uid = :uid2;";
        $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $que->bindParam(':title', $title);
        $que->bindParam(':title2', $title);
        $que->bindParam(':uid', $uid);
        $que->bindParam(':uid2', $uid);
        try {
                $que->execute();
                $que->nextRowset();
                $row = $que->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO thread_messages(threadID, message_body, poster) VALUES (:row, :body, :uid)";
                $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $que->bindParam(':row', $row[0]);
                $que->bindParam(':body', $body);
                $que->bindParam(':uid', $uid);
                try { $que->execute(); }catch(PDOException $e){} 
        }catch(PDOException $e){}
    }
}
```

Now... I thought I was being clever in how i was doing this, but it turned out not to work at all. If a user creates two topics with the same title (Test and Test) then the message that they're posting will only be visible under one topic as opposed to two different topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your threadID column is an auto-increment column, you don't need to have the second query in your first string. Just use the `PDO::lastInsertId()` method to get the resulting auto increment ID from the first query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_threads(title,uid,postDate) VALUES(:title, :uid, NOW())";
$que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$que->bindParam(':title', $title);
$que->bindParam(':uid', $uid);
try
{
    $que->execute();
    $threadID = $this->db->lastInsertId();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO thread_messages(threadID, message_body, poster) VALUES (:row, :body, :uid)";
            $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $que->bindParam(':row', $threadID);
            $que->bindParam(':body', $body);
            $que->bindParam(':uid', $uid);
            try { $que->execute(); }catch(PDOException $e){} 
}
catch(PDOException $e){}
```

Comment: Hai, I found this spare `"`, I think you left it lying around :)

Comment: That did it! I didn't know that function existed! thank you kind sir and or madam.